# Why do some of my citations have a different formatting?

Tags: macos, endnote, iwork-pages

I'm using EndNote X4 to handle my references in Pages '09. When I add or edit citations in a certain chapter, they're automatically formatted in bold italic (sometimes in just bold). Then I individually reformat all the references, even though it doesn't last much time.

As soon as I add or edit again, all my citations within this chapter get bold italic again. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: I don't know about what EndNote does, but my guess is that for citations, a certain paragraph style is applied. After you change this style individually, have you tried "[redefining the style from the selection](http://i.imgur.com/n4HWE.png)"? It's in the "style drawer" when you right-click a style.

Comment: I have tried that a couple of times, but I don't seem to find any paragraph style for citations. Also, there's no bold italic style, http://cl.ly/6xfV.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and a similar solution to @Chris. In my case, I highlighted the entire block of references and selected the "normal" style. At this point, all special formatting was removed from the reference list. After this, I clicked on "Update Citations and Bibliography" and the desired output style was applied correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this guide](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1074649?threadID=1074649&tstart=45) will help you? It specifically mentions formatting using paragraph styles. But it's a tad older.

There's an [Endnote FAQ entry](http://www.endnote.com/support/faqs/CWYW/faq52.asp) that also deals with this topic, at least in some way:

> I have changed my output style from the EndNote program, but the style in my paper keeps reverting to Annotated or some other style I did not choose. How can I correct this?

The solution apparently is:

> Go to the "Edit" Menu and choose "EndNote Citations> Bibliographic format." Select the style directly from this menu.
>
> To use a style not on the menu, quit Pages and go to EndNote X2 or later program.
>   In EndNote, go to the Edit Menu and choose "Output Styles > Open Style Manager." 
>   Here, simply place a check in the "Favorites" box in front of the desired Style.
>
> To use the style in Pages 09, close both Pages and EndNote and then open them to see the style in Pages.

Let me know if that works out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same annoying problem, but just in one document. To fix this, I selected the paragraph where the bolding of citations was occurring and then I opened the styles drawer. The body style had a red inverted triangle next to it. I clicked that and selected revert to defined style. All of the bolded citations in the paragraph went away. And when I added a second paragraph and made a citation, the bolding did not occur.

Best of luck.